# How to use RiverPod with RefreshIndicator

Tags: riverpod

I have a ListView of events with items downloaded via a FutureProvider<List>, works perfect, the AsyncValue does the error and loading widgets also.
I want to wrap the ListView in a RefreshIndicator, so that if the user pulls the list down, it gets reloaded.

What's the best way to do this? Can I simply call provider.refresh() in the onRefresh: line?

```
final eventListAsync = ref.watch(eventProvider);
return eventListAsync.when(
    data: (eventList) {
      eventList.sort((a, b) => a.startTimestamp.compareTo(b.startTimestamp));
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: eventList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return eventCard(eventList[index], context);
          });
    },
    error: (err, stack) {
      var logger = Logger();
      logger.d("Error:$err Stack:$stack");
      return Column( children: [

           Text('Error: $err'),

    ]); },
    loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ref.refresh(provider)` to update your list. However, within your `provider` there must be a self-initialization capability.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator.adaptive(
      onRefresh: () => ref.refresh(provider),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Text('Hello, World!'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For more complex cases (e.g. when using `[Async]Notifier`) use a separate update method where the following logic would be:

```dart
void refreshState() {
  state = AsyncLoading();
  state = AsyncValue.guard(() => /* call the get data method */ );
}
```

Then in build method:

```dart
return RefreshIndicator.adaptive(
      onRefresh: ref.watch(provider.notifier).refreshState,
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Text('Hello, World!'),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: I use riverpod 2, and apparently the first solution doesn't work *sigh*. I guess I have to use a Notifier